# Accessing a function from a different function inside module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I'm working on refactoring some code in JavaScript, a language I am not all too familiar with so I am having some issues understanding some of the bugs I'm facing.

The original code, which worked fine was in this format:

```
function doSomething(website){
//logic
}

function doSomethingElse(value){
   doSomething(value);
}
```

However, I had to put all the existing code inside a module export statement as I need to integrate it with other services. So now the code looks a little like:

```
module.exports = class DoAllThings{
  doSomething(website){
  //logic
  }

  doSomethingElse(value){
   doSomething(value);
  }
}
```

However this doesn't work as it says doSomething is not a function. I have tried setting the function to a var and accessing it that way, and accessing via .this as:

```
 this.doSomething(value);
```

to no avail.

I have defined the module exports as a class so I can do this in another file:

```
 let accessVar = new DoAllThings(); 
 accessVar.doSomethingElse(value);
```

And there are other "classes" I will have to integrate following the pattern. So does anyone have any idea how I would go about accessing these functions? I figure it has something to do with the way I am returning things but I am not too sure.

Comment: The snippet with the exported class contains syntax errors. You need a closing `}`, and class methods can't be declared using `function foo () {}`. Could you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: In `doSomethingElse`, invoke with `this.doSomething()`.

Comment: Fixed the example to more follow my actual code.

Comment: @vox I have already tried that to no help :/

Comment: Why did you change something that was a static module to a `class` that needed to be instantiated? Don't use `class` syntax if you don't have instance state. Export a plain object literal.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
//I am kinda private, can't be accesed from outside
function doSomethingElse() {
  console.log('something else');
}
module.exports = {
  doSomething: function() {
    doSomethingElse();
  }
}

...

const yourModule = require('yourModule');
yourModule.doSomething() //console.log
```

Another:

```
const doSomethingElse = function() {
  console.log('something else')
}
const doSomething = function() {
  doSomethingElse();
}

module.exports = {doSomething}

//or
module.exports = {doSomething, doSomethingElse}
```

With a class:

```
module.exports = class Y {
  doSomething() {
    this.doSomethingElse();
  }

  doSomethingElse() {
    console.log('something else');
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to access these as variables of a class outside this file, which is why I cannot simply use module.exports. Also, the rest of the codebase is also using the same pattern, so I don't really want to break away from it, just understand if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't understand. You will require this from wherever you need access, instantiate (if you have a class) and access whatever public property or method you have.

Comment: Check my third example